# How do I set the default zoom when viewing PDFs in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, pdf

In Mac OS X 10.14, Safari defaults to "zoom to fit" when opening a PDF.

There used to be a WebKitPDFScaleFactor item in the safari.plist but I don't think it exists anymore.

How do I change the default to just "100%" so that I don't need to press command+0 every time I open a PDF?